# Automatically resize iframe when clicking links within the iframe (same domain)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Here is what i have for the javascript so far and It works exactly Like i need it too for the main shop page. however what I am trying to do is get the iframe to resize every time a link within the Iframe is clicked. can anyone help here please?.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function autoResize(id){ var newheight; var newwidth;

if(document.getElementById){
    newheight=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight;
    newwidth=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document.body.scrollWidth;
}
    document.getElementById(id).height= (newheight) + "px";
    document.getElementById(id).width= (newwidth) + "px"; 
}
</script>
```

And Thank you again in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution to your current issue is to just add an event listener for the iframe's load. Clicking a link to load a new page in the iframe will cause the `load` event to fire on the iframe when the new page is loaded. Then you can resize the iframe. **[Live demo (click).](http://plnkr.co/edit/d37npAf21455syxt7ST9?p=preview)**

```
var myIframe = document.getElementById('myIframe');

myIframe.addEventListener('load', function() {
  setIframeHeight();
});
```

On newer browsers, you can use Mutation Observers to make iframe resize for most changes that occur within it. Here's an example. **[Live demo (click).](http://plnkr.co/edit/bkWX1j6D7uuImfExQKgC?p=preview)**

```
var $myIframe = $('#myIframe');
var myIframe = $myIframe[0];

var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver;

myIframe.addEventListener('load', function() {
  setIframeHeight();

  var target = myIframe.contentDocument.body;

  var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    setIframeHeight();
  });

  var config = {
    attributes: true,
    childList: true,
    characterData: true,
    subtree: true
  };
  observer.observe(target, config);
});

myIframe.src = 'iframe.html';

function setIframeHeight() {
  $myIframe.height('auto');
  var newHeight = $('html', myIframe.contentDocument).height();
  $myIframe.height(newHeight);
}
```

Comment: Ok So using the above code I add that to the main.js page under the Iframe section in main.js 

and to call on the function in my html5 index page I use

    '<iframe id="Iframe" src="./shop/index.php"></iframe>'

Naturally I have edited the "myIframe" to Iframe because there is two seperate pages on the single page that will be called upon.

Comment: @PutneyPC I'm sorry, I don't understand. Do you have a question? Also, did you see I updated with a much simpler solution (at the top). I just prefer the much more feature rich Mutation Observers.

Comment: Well the simpler solution is fine but for one thing...

I get a syntax error at the end of it

Comment: @PutneyPC you can see in my demo that my code works and has no syntax error. The dev tools tell you where the syntax error is. You should have no problem correcting a simple mistake.

Comment: ok I found the problem - I still had some of the old code directly above it  causing the issue my apologies